# ssl ertificate and https connection in python3

Tags: python, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use OpenSSL package in python to build ssl secure connection but I got this error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

in `conn.connect()`

It takes me 2 days to debug, and the web address is correct, can somebody find out why?

```
from OpenSSL import SSL

certi_file = p12.get_certificate()     # (signed) certificate object
key_file =p12.get_privatekey()      # private key.
ca_cert = p12.get_ca_certificates() # ca chain.

# ctx = Context(SSLv23_METHOD);
context = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
context.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2)
context.use_certificate(certi_file);
context.use_privatekey(key_file);
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE;
context.check_hostname = None
context.set_verify(VERIFY_PEER | VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT | 
VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE,verify_callback)

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("https//:markets.midwestiso.org/darteor/xml/submit", 80, context=context)
conn.connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link (`"https//:markets.midwestiso.org/darteor/xml/submit"`) seems incorrect. Shouldn't it be like 
    "https://markets.midwestiso.org/darteor/xml/submit".

Comment: Oh I mistyped it in this version but "https://markets.midwestiso.org/darteor/xml/submit". is not working